Swagger UI Page hangs/crashes on .NET 8 API Response
I have a .NET 8 web api using Oracle EF Core provider. It has Swagger UI configured out of the box. I added no additional configuration to swagger UI.
Everytime I invoke a GET operation that has a big payload (let's say ~5,000 records from database), it hangs/crashes. But if I invoke the same endpoint using POSTMAN, I get the payload. This only happens with API operations with big payloads. If I have an endpoint that gets a single user, swagger UI works no problem. POST/PUT/DELETE all work. Just any GET operation with big payload. If anyone is wondering the size of the payload: 1.74 MB.
Is there any solution to this? I updated the Swashbuckle Swagger nuget package, but that didn't seem to solve the problem.
I also use DTO objects so domain entities are not an issue. I checked my entities and there are no relational keys of any sort which can cause issues (referencing other similar but older stackoverflow questions).
What I tried:

Used DTO objects for API Response so domain entities are not returned
Updated Swashbuckle/Swagger packages
Repo queries dbcontext with AsNoTracking()


It sounds to me like it's browser related, e.g. because your browser is overloaded.
Is there any reason why you have see all of these records in your browser?

@Lucas , what a point! I tried on Edge and it worked. Must be browser related. Thanks much for the help!

My question then becomes, how do I make this work in Chrome?
I cleared memory, cache, etc. It did load the response, but the UI almost becomes unresponsive in chrome.

Take a look at this one, you could disable the syntax highlighting in swagger to improve the performance: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3832#issuecomment-2017322174
